# Xamarin.iOS Simulator not display

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, xamarin-studio

I am new to Xamarin world. When I start running my app with Xamarin studio and launch Simulator it will display below error and does not start Simulator. If this is basic question then i apologise but how to solve this problem.

I search on google and SO but nothing will help me.

Error logcat :

> Failed to launch the simulator: Could not load the framework
>   'IDEFoundation' (path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation):
>   dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation,
>   1): Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/DVTAnalytics.framework/Versions/A/DVTAnalytics   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation
>   Reason: image not found error MT1008: Failed to launch the simulator:
>   Could not load the framework 'IDEFoundation' (path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation):
>   dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation,
>   1): Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/DVTAnalytics.framework/Versions/A/DVTAnalytics   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation
>   Reason: image not found

Comment: Can it works in XCode?

Comment: @AlancLiu yes it work in Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **uninstall** the whole `Xamarin Studio`. And Then **Install** it again. It will solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do u use the latest stable version of Xamarin.Fomrs?

Comment: I am not using Xamarin.Form and yes i have `stable` version ?